# Is there a way to convert a string array of numbers in alphabetic form, into their numeric form?

Tags: java, arrays, string, int, theory

I'm still new to java but I had a question regarding a theory I wanted to test. I wanted to know if there was a way to write a program that would convert a string array of numbers, written out in letters like one, two, three, etc, into their numeric forms as integers. Is this actually possible? I don't have any example code as I have yet to test this out. But some answers would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You'd likely want to create a map for looking up string values into integers.

```
Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("one", 1);
map.put("two", 2);
map.put("three", 3);
map.put("four", 4);
```

etc

Then you would parse your string and look it up in the map

```
String text = "four"
Integer value = map.get(text);
```

If you have an array of things to convert, then you'd have to loop on it, and obviously your parsing would get more complicated with a wider range of possible string values, ex: "Four Thousand Thirty Five"

Answer (score 0):

Generaly, I figure out this kind of issue with a "configuration over implementation" pattern.
May I share with you a solution for your question.

Java offer us the possibility to store huge couples of key/value in a property file and to request it for a mapping as often as we need.
So I would have store this file : **string2int.properties** :

```
zero:0
one:1
two:2 
three:3
four:4
five:5
six:6
seven:7
eight:8
nine:9
```

This is the format for *.properties* files

And then I can access the value of a key this way thanks to **Properties** object:

```
    Properties properties = new Properties(); 
    try { 
        FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream("string2int.properties");
        properties.load(input);
        System.out.println("one is : " + properties.getProperty("one"));
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Output :

```
one is : 1
```

Comment: Fine as far as it goes, and what I'd do too, but "nine hundred and seventy five" is not so amenable to that approach :-)   The OP is not really clear whether he's talking about numbers (so 975 is one number) or digits (so 975 is three digits).

Answer (score 0):

You'll need ten, elleven, twelve, thirteen, ... , twenty, thirty, .. ninety, hundred, thousand, million.. in your property file as well. Then you'll have to parse the written numbers.

"two hundred and twelve thousand and three" has to be (2x100 + 12) x 1000 + 3.

With the above number you know that you have to stop at hundred and multiply with two. You also know that when you get "thousand" whatever's at it's left must be multiplied with 1000. Unless there's also a million somewhere to the left.

I tried with an example that starts at the right end, the least significant numbers. I take a note of the key-numbers 100 and 1000 and do a recursive calculation. I didn't include a property file, but used a map instead. If there's a mapping for a word, it's added to the list, unless it's "and". If there's no mapping for a word, the program breaks down with a NullPointerException.

Please note that this code should NOT be used in any production environment. It's not a parser and it doesn't take corner cases of language into account.

Also note that there's no detection of illegal written numbers, such as "one two thousand ninety ninety hundred five four". This will just come out as 3000 + 18000 + 9

```
public class TextToNumber{
  public static void main(String[] args){
    String s;
    TextToNumber textToNumber = new TextToNumber();

    s = "four";
    System.out.println(s);
    System.out.println(textToNumber.translateNumber(s));

    System.out.println("----");
    s = "one hundred";
    System.out.println(s);
    System.out.println(textToNumber.translateNumber(s));

    System.out.println("----");
    s = "five thousand";
    System.out.println(s);
    System.out.println(textToNumber.translateNumber(s));

    System.out.println("----");
    s = "twelve thousand two hundred fifty six";
    System.out.println(s);
    System.out.println(textToNumber.translateNumber(s));

    System.out.println("----");
    s = "two hundred and twelve thousand and three";
    System.out.println(s);
    System.out.println(textToNumber.translateNumber(s));

    System.out.println("----");
    s = "one two thousand ninety ninety hundred five four";
    System.out.println(s);
    System.out.println(textToNumber.translateNumber(s));
  }

  Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
  public TextToNumber() {
    map.put("one", 1);
    map.put("two", 2);
    map.put("three", 3);
    map.put("four", 4);
    map.put("five", 5);
    map.put("six", 6);
    map.put("seven", 7);
    map.put("eight", 8);
    map.put("nine", 9);
    map.put("ten", 10);
    map.put("eleven", 11);
    map.put("twelve", 12);
    map.put("thirteen", 13);
    map.put("fourteen", 14);
    map.put("fifteen", 15);
    map.put("sixteen", 16);
    map.put("seventeen", 17);
    map.put("eighteen", 18);
    map.put("nineteen", 19);
    map.put("twenty", 20);
    map.put("thirty", 30);
    map.put("fourty", 40);
    map.put("fifty", 50);
    map.put("sixty", 60);
    map.put("seventy", 70);
    map.put("eighty", 80);
    map.put("ninety", 90);
    map.put("hundred", 100);
    map.put("thousand", 1000);
  }

  public int translateNumber(String text){
    List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>(10);

    if (text == null) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Number cannot be empty");

    // borrowed from https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/text/word.html
    BreakIterator wordIterator = BreakIterator.getWordInstance();
    wordIterator.setText(text);

    int start = wordIterator.first();
    int end = wordIterator.next();

    while (end != wordIterator.DONE) {
        String word = text.substring(start,end);
        if (Character.isLetterOrDigit(word.charAt(0))) {
            if (!("and".equals(word))) numbers.add(map.get(word));
        }
        start = end;
        end = wordIterator.next();
    }

    System.out.println(numbers);
    return recursiveCalculation(numbers);
  }

  private int recursiveCalculation(List<Integer> list){
    int result = 0;
    int index1000 = list.lastIndexOf(Integer.valueOf(1000));
    int index100  = list.lastIndexOf(Integer.valueOf(100));

    // add all numbers that's to the right of the hundred marker
    //  (or 1000 marker in case there's no hundred marker)
    result += add(list, Math.max(index100+1,Math.max(index1000+1,0)), list.size());

    if (index100 != -1 && index100 > index1000) {
      result += 100 * recursiveCalculation(list.subList(index1000+1,index100));
    }

    if (index1000 != -1) {
      result += 1000 * recursiveCalculation(list.subList(0,index1000));
    }

    return result;
  }

  private int add(List<Integer> list, int begin, int end) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = begin; i < end; i++) {
      sum += list.get(i);
    }
    return sum;
  }
}
```

Here's the result:

```
C:\..snip..>java -cp compiled/default TextToNumber
four
[4]
4
----
one hundred
[1, 100]
100
----
five thousand
[5, 1000]
5000
----
twelve thousand two hundred fifty six
[12, 1000, 2, 100, 50, 6]
12256
----
two hundred and twelve thousand and three
[2, 100, 12, 1000, 3]
212003
----
one two thousand ninety ninety hundred five four
[1, 2, 1000, 90, 90, 100, 5, 4]
21009
```